# Print our char structure and length

Tags: c, structure

My structure has a nested structure but it only consists of chars.
Ex:

```
typedef struct {
     otherstruc struct2;
     char b[100];
}mainstruct;

typedef struct {
    char a[10];
}otherstruc;
```

Sometimes I am able to print the structure as a string but other times the program crashes. Ex:

```
printf("Main struct = %s\n", mainstruct);
```

What would be the correct way to print the contents of the structure?

Comment: Why are you trying that? why don't just `printf("Main struct = %s\n", mainstruct.b);`

Comment: You can't "print" a structure, you have to print each member separately, like e.g. `printf("%s %s", myMainstruct.struct2.a, myMainstruct.b);`

Comment: You can't just pass a `char[]` to match a`"%s"`.  You need a `'\0'` terminated string.

Comment: And it would be nice to have some actual code.  In your samples `mainstruct` is a type, so it cannot be passed as an argument to a function.

Comment: if you mean to pass an instance of `mainstruct` directly to printf, the compiler my accept that, passing it by value, but this is definitely not what `printf` expects

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("Main struct = %s\n", mainstruct);
```

is the wrong way to print. You cannot print a structure *all at a time*. You need to print *element by element* of a variable of that structure type. You need to use something like

```
mainstruct struct1;
```

and

```
printf("struct1.struct2.a %s\n", struct1.struct2.a);
printf("struct1.b value %s\n", struct1.b);
```

Note:

1. to use a `char` array as *string*, it needs to be null-terminated.
2. `mainstruct` is having a variable of type `otherstruc`. So, the definition of `otherstruc` has to come before `mainstruct`.

Comment: Also put a note on declaring `otherstruc` [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28660636/2455888) `mainstruct`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your code will not compile because at `otherstruc struct2;` line in `struct` `mainstruct` compiler has no idea what is it. So, declare `otherstruct` first:

```
typedef struct {
    char a[10];
}otherstruc;

typedef struct {
     otherstruc struct2;
     char b[100];
}mainstruct;
```

Now you should note that you can't print a structure but its instance. First instantiate it

```
mainstruct instance;
```

To print the contents you need to access it's fields like this

```
printf("mainstruct.b         = %s\n", instance.b)
printf("mainstruct.struct2.a = %s\n", instance.struct2.a);
```

Comment: @haccks Oh didn't notice that.

Comment: If it were my answer then it would look like this. :)

Comment: @haccks what can I say, it's a lot better, if youl'd like I can delete it if your post your answer.